# How to build a layout out of parts that have their own layouts and behaviors

Tags: android

I'm writing an app that has 2 tabs created this way:

```
ActionBar.Tab tab1, tab2;
Fragment fragmentTab1 = new VesselFragment();
Fragment fragmentTab2 = new CrucibleFragment();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.vessel);
    tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.crucible);

    tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab1));
    tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab2));

    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);
}
```

As far as I understand each tab is a Fragment. But my problem is that both tabs are very simliar(I have to have 2 separate tabs nevertheless). They both have an EditText, a Spinner and a TableLayout. But CrucibleFragment also has an additional TableLayout and some other additional views. VesselFragment on the other hand has some other View that is not present in CrucibleFragment. Of course, the parts that are in both Fragments are behaving exactly the same.

The way I have it now is 2 separate Fragments, each having its own layout and own code for handling the views behavior. The problem is that as I said, the fragments are very similiar in many places and the code in CrucibleFragment and VesselFragment are almost copies of each other, as are the layouts that they inflate. When i try to add some UI feature that applies to both tabs, I want to only do it in one place in the code and one place in the XML, not 2 code and 2XML's.

I had an idea on how to solve this- create some kinds of parts, that each have a simple layout and simple code to handle them. So one part for a TableLayout, Spinner and EditText that both tabs share and some other parts that are only present in some specific tabs.

I could create a superclass and have the fragments extend that class, but I would still have to have copies of the layouts. I thought this could be done by using fragments, but there is very little information on how to achieve what I want on the internet.

What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into this [Re-using Layouts with `<include/>]`[1](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html). You can put the elements you want to re-use in the layout that you will include in the in the layouts for CrucibleFragment and VesselFragment. In the layout of your fragments you can add additional elements. In the superclass that you will create, you could try and access the elements that are in the included layout (after inflating in both your CrucibleFragment and VesselFragment).

Comment: I have a small followup. With this, i will have 2 separate tabs inflated with one XML, which means that both the tabs will refer to the same Views. This means that when, for example an EditText that is shared between the two tabs contains some text, it will be visible in both tabs, which is an unwanted behavior. Is there some way to get around that?

Comment: Never mind. After some testing I figured out that you can actually give <include>s their ID and then search for the views inside an instance of <include> by first finding it by ID.